# Jhipster: What path should be set for user files

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

I put some *.xls files to src/main/resources/templates/clientdocs  folder.
and trying to

```
private static final String FILEIN_NAME = "templates/clientdocs/file1.xls";
....
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(FILEIN_NAME))
```

Also i tried

```
  "classpath:templates/clientdocs/file1.xls"
```

But in both cases i get that file not found.
What is correct path should be?

Comment: I put file to src/main/webapp and set FILEIN_NAME = "file1.xls" . File not found.

Comment: No, just src/main/webapp

Comment: I tried both  src/main/webapp/public and rc/main/webapp/static
with :
      private static final String FILEIN_NAME = "file1.xlsx";
and  witj
private static final String FILEIN_NAME = "classpath:file.xlsx";
The same. 
This file is used as static content

Comment: I tried as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804262 , but get NPE  in InputStream fis = resource.getInputStream())

Comment: Yes, i tried this too.

Comment: Which url did you use in browser ? Have you checked server log? Have you checked that xls files are copied to target/classes  folder?

Comment: I didn't use browser , i just  started in console  ./mvnw .  And yes. xls files are in target/classes folder.  I tried to debug  :

private static final String TOVNAKL_FILEIN_NAME = "file.xlsx";
File newFile = new File(FILEIN_NAME);
        log.debug(" Attempting to read from file in:" + newFile.getCanonicalPath());

In that case path is root folder where my project is.

When i use 
private static final String TOVNAKL_FILEIN_NAME = "classpath:file.xls";
path is:  project_folder/classpath:/file.xls

Comment: When i put xls to project folder where yo-rc.json, pom.xml 
and use 
private static final StringFILEIN_NAME = "file.xls";

it worked

Comment: Sorry, I got the wrong understanding that you wanted to serve this file over web, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your file in your resources, e.g `src/main/resources/clientdocs/file1.xls` and then use a `ClassPathResource`.

```
Resource xlsRes = new ClassPathResource("clientdocs/file1.xls");
InputStream xlsStream = xlsRes.getInputStream();
```