# IntelliJ Java 11 resources from submodules are not accessible

Tags: intellij-idea, java-11

I have a problem when I build my application in IntelliJ.

If I'have 2 modules:

> application;
>   application.gui

In application gui under ressources folder I have an image /layout/image/background.jpg

And in this module a call this image I recieved  eroor that it is not exist.  This is only IntelliJ packaging problem, because the same project build in maven works fine.

How should I configure my IntelliJ to make it works ?

https://gitlab.com/mszymkowiak/simgentree/tree/simgentree-start/simgentree.project

It is not related [How to access a resource file in src/main/resources/ folder in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804262/how-to-access-a-resource-file-in-src-main-resources-folder-in-spring-boot)

Because the files are probably NOT visibly by IntelliJ built.  I;ve tried this solution and it return always null for my submodule.
I have same problem in my JavaFX application in Java11 in intelliJ
 ( same application in java8 works fine, but when run it from IntelliJ any resources from submodule are not visible)

```
   System.out.println("Empty path exist ? : "+ resourceLoader.getResource("").exists());
   System.out.println("mainbackground path exits ? :  " +resourceLoader.getResource("layout/images/mainbackground.jpg").exists());
```

Gives :

```
Empty path exist ? : false
mainbackground path exits ? :  false
```

@Edit
I added to resource folder named : static and moved there files, and it seems to works. But I would like to know, why it doesn't  works when static is not there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a resource file in src/main/resources/ folder in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804262/how-to-access-a-resource-file-in-src-main-resources-folder-in-spring-boot). add classpath to value

Comment: no it isn't I've seent this before.. and it desnt work. As I explain in maven works Fine. It is IntelliJ problem

Comment: check embedded maven version update as local maven path.  idea-settings - Build- execution -> Deployment -> Build Tolls -> Maven -> Maven Home directory

Answer (score 0):

Java 11 not compatible with IDEA embedded maven version. Update it with your local maven re-try
[image: update-maven]

Comment: I use maven 3.6. As I mentionned jar compiled by maven is ok. Only from IntelliJ.  And only when in ressource I dont have static folder. If I moved all my folders to static it works

Comment: Spring boot auoto configuration scan static for resources by default.  It seems that's the reason.  You need to read as claspath.